# Is the reuse of descriptor states in Boost ASIO's epoll back-end safe?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, epoll

ASIO's `epoll_reactor` back-end associates a `descriptor_state` with each file descriptor by means of a pointer stored in `data.ptr` of the `epoll_event` submitted to `epoll_ctl`.

When a descriptor gets retired, either because the associated socket is closed or destroyed, `epoll_reactor::deregister_descriptor` returns the `descriptor_state` to an `object_pool`, which maintains a free list of descriptor states.

At this point, the `descriptor_state` can be reused again when a new socket is to be created.

Let's assume that there are multiple worker threads calling `io_service.run()`. What makes sure that an outstanding epoll_wait call won't return an epoll_event with data.ptr referring to the old `descriptor_state`, which may have already been reused?